# How to make a macro out of a Private Sub?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5 
End Sub
```

I want to make this code work in the worksheet, but it won't save as a macro or run because the module only accepts the `Sub () End Sub` syntax. What do I do?

Comment: Is this an `.xlsm` file or `.xlsx`?

Comment: it's a '.xlsm' @harrymc

Comment: What exactly happens?

Comment: I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @harrymc  when i write the code in ThisWorksheet and run it it asks to name a macro, I do that, then, when it makes a code in the module, it makes a 'Sub() End Sub' code and if i change that to the code I mentioned it asks to make a new macro, then when I do that it makes yet a new 'Sub() End Sub' syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[Worksheet.Change event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)
is an event routine, not a macro that can be run manually.

As specified in the documentation, it will run automatically
"when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link".

To test the routine, you need to modify the value of the cell(s).

Comment: thank you, but now i have another question: i tried using the code as a button and if the cells change i wanted it t do something and when i clicked the button it gave an error because there's something in the brackets of Private Sub (). how do i fix this? @harrymc

Comment: Better create a separate post for this question with all detail such as a screenshot of the error.

Comment: all right. thank you.